# django framework to create homepage

Tags: python, html, css, django

Installed django framework and created an app for my homepage. Added app to settings in project folder. Able to get html running however css won't style it. My html, css file is inside appfolder/templates/appfolder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Static files like CSS and Javascript files don't belong the `templates` folder. You should put them in `static` folder. I suggest you check [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/intro/tutorial06/).

Also, just for future reference, even if static files are served by Django development server on the development environment, you will need to set up your web server to serve those on a production environment.